# Combine divs within a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Is it possible to use a JavaScript for loop to combine a number of div's? I have 16 sets of these I am wanting to put into a for loop. The problem I am having is that its HTML not JavaScript I am trying to do this with. I haven't seen anything so far on how to go about this. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

What the following code does is catch the data pre-defined from a 16X17 table and inserts it into one cell in my document. I then have have other code using the div id's that makes visible just the one I need.

```
<div id="101" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a1)</script></div>
<div id="102" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a2)</script></div>
<div id="103" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a3)</script></div>
<div id="104" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a4)</script></div>
<div id="105" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a5)</script></div>
<div id="106" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a6)</script></div>
<div id="107" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a7)</script></div>
<div id="108" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a8)</script></div>
<div id="109" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a9)</script></div>
<div id="110" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a10)</script></div>
<div id="111" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a11)</script></div>
<div id="112" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a12)</script></div>
<div id="113" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a13)</script></div>
<div id="114" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a14)</script></div>
<div id="115" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a15)</script></div>
<div id="116" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a16)</script></div>
<div id="117" class="hidden"><script>document.write(tab1a17)</script></div>
```

Update: Pulling data from table

```
<!--Start- Takes Assembly number from Data Table-->  <!--Change "<Col1;" equala columns-->
    for (var x = 1; x<Col1; x++){window["aa"+x] = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[0].cells[x+1].innerHTML;}
<!--End--- Takes Assembly number from Data Table-->

<!--Start- Takes Assembly Rows from Data Table-->    <!--Change "<Row1;" equals rows-->
    for (var y = 1; y<Row1+1; y++){window["rows"+y] = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[y].cells[1].innerHTML;}
<!--End- Takes Assembly Rows from Data Table-->

<!--Start- Takes Part number from Data Table-->      <!-- "<Col1;" equals columns----> <!-- If a Column is added to main table add a new line below---->
    for (var z1 =  1; z1 <Col1; z1++) {window["tab1a"+z1]   = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[1].cells[z1  +1].innerHTML;}
    for (var z2 =  1; z2 <Col1; z2++) {window["tab2a"+z2]   = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[2].cells[z2  +1].innerHTML;}
    for (var z3 =  1; z3 <Col1; z3++) {window["tab3a"+z3]   = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[3].cells[z3  +1].innerHTML;}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. In general, it seems you should read about DOM manipulation in JavaScript... Document.write has been considered obsolete for years

Comment: What's the *end-result* you're after? Your code example is...unclear. At best.

Comment: My code is already finished and it works as it should. I am just wanting to make it easier, and quicker to edit and make it shorter. These repeating divs are repeated throughout the document 17 times. This document is 2081 lines of code.

Comment: Okay, so the bottom part is where you should be adding that data to an array rather than creating a bunch of sequentially named global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who gave suggestions. I spent a few more hours with the code and came up with the following. It works great in testing. I can now add and remove rows and columns from my table without having to change the code.

```
for (var w =  1; w <Row1; w++)  
for (var z1 =  1; z1 <Col1; z1++) {window["tab" + w + "a" + z1]  = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[w].cells[z1 +1].innerHTML;}
```

This replaces my 17 lines of the following:

```
for (var z17 =  1; z17 <Col1; z17++) {window["tab17a"+z17]   = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[17].cells[z17  +1].innerHTML;}
```

This is very good because my new table has 50+ rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try using AngularJS (which is a javascript framework that you can easily add to your html page (see AngularJS.com for a quick intro))

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='myApp'>

    <div ng-repeat='entry in entries'>
      <div id={{entry.id}} class="hidden"><script>document.write({{entry.table}})</script></div>

    </div>

<script src='app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then within a controller in a file called app.js you would make a array of objects 1...100 or whatever number you want and pass it to a scope like this

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.entries = [{
id: '101', table: 'tab1a1'}, {id: '102', table: 'tab1a2'}]

// extend to your own range

});
```

Comment: I haven't used AngularJS but it looks promising. I hope it will work on our server. I tried using Jquery before which would work in my browser but not our production server. I will see if any other suggestions come in first before I try it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Jonathon JavaScript runs on the client, in their browser. It shouldn't matter what webserver is serving the code.

Comment: @AMG, are you sure that you can template a script tag? Or that doing so will achieve the effect he wants? A template might execute that script multiple times during compilation, no? And they may have explicitly disabled it for security reasons, since it's almost like a backdoor 'eval'. I've never seen anyone attempt this, so it may work, but on the other hand I think there are very good reasons not to use this approach even if it does work (it's like eight anti-patterns in one).

Comment: I think its the way that corporate runs their own hearder before ours and our documents has its own header. I have never seen this before and suprised it even works. When the document runs in production and you view source there is defenately two. They pushed an update to their header which broke most of the scripts. Oh, time to go. I will check back later.

Comment: @JonathanBlaine Are you talking about http headers or are you saying there are two <head> elements in the html?

Comment: Yeah, you definitely have to make sure jquery or angular or whatever is actually included. It doesn't have to be within the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

having a bunch of sequential variables like tab1a1 is difficult to work with. Can you put those in an array? Then...

```
var b=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
for(var i=1; i<18; i++){
    var d=document.createElement('div'); //make a div element
    d.id='10'+i; //assign sequential id
    d.innerHTML=tab1a[i]; //put the the array element content corresponding to that number into the new div element
    b.appendChild(d); //place new element into the DOM
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use excel and basically make a column with on the rows 101,102,103... And a similar same column for the tables. Then just add the code lines in string format and bind the colums together with &. Copy everything and paste this in notepad and then in your code!

Ex:

```
="<div id='" & A1 & "' etc etc
```